# Cryptic clue "Injured person's mostly easy-going (8)"

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

I'm stumped on the last clue in another cryptic crossword. The clue is

> Injured person's mostly easy-going

The (confirmed) cross-clues give C_S_A_T_. Normally I can guess at a part or at least the structure, but I've got nothing here.

<sub>Cryptic Crosswords iPhone app, Pack 3, Puzzle 5, Clue 12</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> CASUALTY is mostly CASUAL

The cryptic part of the clue doesn't seem to cover the whole word, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think it gets out of covering the whole clue because of the *mostly*.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up possible combinations for a word like this one using a Regular Expression search at http://www.dict.org--select one of the two regular expression search options available, and type in the incomplete word, say `^c.s.a.t.$`, in the search field. I find it **most helpful indeed** when I'm stuck.